# weighted vertical LinearLayout with proportionally scaled image and TextView to the right of image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, textview

How to scale image with respect to ratio inside LinearLayout with weights and then put a label to the right of image ? Example below shows 3 rows with equal heights, each need TextView positioned to the right of them. In short: image to the left, text to the right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#33B5E5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a1"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AA66CC"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a2"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF4444"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a3"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is currently wrong with the above layout? Could you post what you have now and what you desire?

Answer (score 0):

The ImageViews widths and height are mostly incorrect for what you want to achieve.

Try this, and then compare the two to work out what was wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#33B5E5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#33B5E5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a1"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#AA66CC" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a2"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF4444" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a3"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that this doesn't display correctly in the ADT tools Graphical Layout - but it does on a device.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking for I would recommend using horizontal linear layouts instead of your relative layouts. This allows you to use weights for your horizontal placement giving you what you want:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF4444"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will make it so that your TextView takes up only the space it needs (on the right) and the image will take up all remaining space (on the left) of the horizontal layout. The horizontal layouts will evenly take up available space within the vertical layout.

NOTE: This will give you a "nested weights are bad for performance" warning, however because this is a simple layout and the nested weights are separate for vertical and horizontal it shouldn't have any noticeable impact on performance. If you were using this over repeating views or had much more complexity to your layout, I would recommend something else.